# Stuck processes need to be killed on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

The kill button on the schedule page isn't working at the moment on pythonanywhere. Any ideas for a work around while I wait for support from the helpful folks at ResolverSys?

I currently can't open a new process from consoles
My scheduled tasks aren't running.

I can however SSH in, so if there is an idea using that I could help myself.

Comment: It would be nice to have been able to tag this with pythonanywhere, but the tag doesn't exist. Anyone with 1500 rep care to fix that?

Comment: we did briefly have a tag, but a mod decided it wasn't yet justified... hopefully now we have a bit more of an SO community, the next attempt to create the tag will stick...

Comment: @hwjp Thanks for the info...:) I'd upvote the next attempt...:)

Comment: I don't understand how this is off topic since Python Anywhere is essentially a developer IDE for Python, thus any problems we have there are developer related. However I will refrain from asking such questions in the future if this remains closed. Anyone willing to add a comment explaining specifically how this is off topic would be helpful I'm not angry or anything. I sincerely want to get it so I can be the best SO member I can be!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out a work around for this problem.

The links to kill on the schedule page include the pid. I was able to extract those pids to use with kill from an ssh session.

So, for instance if your pid is 100 you can take care of it from ssh with

```
kill 100
```

Just replace 100 with your pid from the link to kill the process as listed on the schedule page.

I wish I had thought of it sooner, but hopefully anyone else that has the issue will benefit from this solution.